# Input URL on a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am building a lightning component for a community to display a image which is stored as a URL in User object. I have written the Apex controller and lightning component and java controller as below. but the image doesn't display

Component

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS102/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
<!-- scripts="/resource/Jquery" /> -->

<div class="slds">
    <p>
        <b> LSA</b>
    </p>
   <br>
    </br>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.Users}">
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="padding-right:16px;font-weight: bold;text-transform:uppercase">LSA :</span> {!cell.FullPhotoUrl} </td>
                </tr>  
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Java controllor

```
({
    doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getLSA");
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set("v.Users", data.getReturnValue());
        });
$A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
})
```

Comment: can you share the console log or error message from your browsers dev tools (if any)?

Comment: Can you also please share your Apex controller class which has the query to get the URL field?

Comment: No need to add the **lightning css** and the scope `slds`

Comment: Also, share how you defined the attribute `Users`;

Comment: public class LSAImageController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<User> getLSA() {
        //Get logged in user details
        User loggedInUser = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact_ID_Text__C
                             FROM User
                             WHERE ID=: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
       
        Contact lsaContact = [Select id, LSAID__c FROM Contact 
                           where Id =:loggedInUser.ContactId ];
        
        return [Select Id, FullPhotoUrl From User 
                    where Id =:lsaContact.LSAID__c];
    }    
}

Answer (score 1):

You are almost on the right track here, maybe your Aura attributes are not defined properly. Do take a look at the following for an example. Also, it is recommended to use "force:slds" extension rather than using slds from the static resource as it handles the version upgrades automatically. You don't need to bother about maintaining and versioning your slds static resources.

> **Aura Component / APP**

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="force:slds" controller="LtngCtrler">
    <aura:attribute access="private" name="users" type="User[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.users}">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!cell.FullPhotoUrl}</td>
                    <td><img src="{!cell.FullPhotoUrl}" /></td>
                </tr>  
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</aura:application>
```

> **Controller.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        /*do your action callbacks*/
        var action = component.get("c.getUsers");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            component.set("v.users", response.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

> **Apex Controller :**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<User> getUsers() {
   /* Sample collection - returning a list of users */
   return [Select id, FullPhotoUrl from User];      
}
```

> **Sample Output :**

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, The Apex controller should return only one photo of user who is associated to the Contact object via LSAID__c. The login user ID is link to the Contact

Comment: But this is not the case according to the method getLSA that you have provided in the comments. It returns a list of users, which was why i tailored my answer to return a list of users. Anyway in the above case if you want to fetch photoURL using relationships from a custom object or contact. Do the following. Query all the necessary fields return the custom object or contact. Create an aura:attribute with the return type from apex class, And finally access the value as in any object Notation.

Comment: Also if you want just one user, why did you use aura: iteration in your components?